# ROS AMCL does not need odometry data?

Tags: slam, ros, navigation

I'm reading [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) document on ROS Wiki. In its subscribed topics there is not odometry topic, why? It works only with laser?

**Subscribed Topics:** (From ROS Wiki)

scan (sensor_msgs/LaserScan)

tf (tf/tfMessage)

initialpose (geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped)

map (nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid)

And my next question is how can I use `amcl` in `Gazebo` simulator for turtlebot? Any tutorial available?

Answer (score 3):

amcl receives the integrated odometry information over the tf topic between base_link and odom and then computes the correction between the odom frame and the map frame as the odometry accumulates drift.

Frames are defined in [REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html)